# .htaccess rewrite more than one rule doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've read up on several resources on how to do rewrites, and had some success with the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~me/website.net/html/
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ property.php?property=$1
```

...which I probably don't need to tell you converts...

```
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/property-name
```

...to ....

```
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/property.php?property=property-name
```

No matter how much I read I cannot figure out the next phase of what I need to do which is convert...

```
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/1
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/property/property-name
```

To...

```
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/index.php?page=1
http://imac-i3.local/~me/website.net/html/property.php?property-name
```

Any help would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You want to change your rule from `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ property.php?property=$1` to:

```
RewriteRule ^property/(.*)$ property.php?property=$1 [L]
```

And add this for the pagination (it can be after the rules that you already have):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```